While using Spring Cloud Gateway and configuring the circuit breaker, the server crashes
resilience4j:
  circuitbreaker:
    configs:
      default:
        sliding_window_size: 100 
        slow-call-duration-threshold: 9500
        permitted_number_of_calls_in_half_open_state: 10
        minimum_number_of_calls: 10
        wait_duration_in_open_state: 10s
        failure_rate_threshold: 75
        event_consumer_buffer_size: 2000

When making continuous calls that result in a timeout, the server does not crash, but when applying the circuit breaker, the server crashes. What should I do?
I thought that when the circuit opens, it would immediately return errors, and the gateway would continue to function normally.
